# A guide to p-integrable functions and their usage

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

In a failed attempt to solve this seemingly straightforward problem...

[How do I show that a distribution is locally p-integrable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211507/show-that-a-distribution-is-locally-p-integrable-when-its-first-order-distributi)

...I realized that I don't understand these spaces as deeply as I would like to. For example, my (naive) way of thinking of a function $f \in L^p_{loc}$ is as a "pseudo"-$L^p$ function which is only integrable on "small" (compact) regions. Is that the right intuition? If not, what would be a better way of thinking about it?

**A few more questions to address**

> 1) Other than their definitions, what are some major conceptual and practical differences between the $L^p$ and $L^p_{loc}$ spaces?
>
> 2) Which non-trivial classes (if any) are dense in $L^p_{loc}$
>
> 3) Which are the most commonly used methods and techniques when dealing with the above spaces? (Ex: Holder's inequality? Density arguments? etc)

Comment: To get some perspective, every continuous function is locally integrable, but not necessarily integrable on the whole space.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That should be a direct application of the extreme value theorem, correct?